# How to make a text to speech work in background in React Native app?

Tags: react-native, background, text-to-speech

I have a question that I have not been able to solve for some time and I have not been able to do it yet. Do you know how to make a text to speech work in background React Native Android app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sounds to work on iOS in background mode you need to do 2 things:

enable audio capabilities in xcode
configure AVAudioSession. There is already a package for it here: https://github.com/BonnierNews/react-native-audio-session
I did this at the root of the project, using react-native-sound, but should be the same with react-native-audio-session:

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

Sound.setCategory('Playback'); // this will play sound in background
```

Somewhere in your background runner:

```
Tts.speak('Some text);
```

Comment: Hello, in my case what should i use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239362/how-can-i-control-in-change-play-sound-in-the-background-ios

Answer (score -1):

We can use **ACCESSIBILITY**.Accessibility, means making your apps usable to both normal users and users with disabilities. Any person can have one or more form of disability. 
**Step1:-**
Turn on **TalkBack** in your device Settings 
Open your device's Settings app Settings app.>>Open Accessibility>> then TalkBack.>>Turn on TalkBack.
then add  following props to every component of ReactNative.
    accessible={true}
     accessibilityLabel={label}
Like this:-

```
 return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              accessible={true}
              accessibilityLabel={label}
              accessibilityTraits={"button"}
              accessibilityComponentType={"button"}
              onPress={() => {
                onPress(data.name);
              }}
            >
              <Icon
                name={icon}
                style={styles.icon}
                size={icon_size}
                color={icon_color}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )
```